# Datatables search for clicked div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I am fetching the categories this way.

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category):?>
    <div id="search"><a href=""><?php echo $category->category;?></a></div></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

e.g. this gives me categories

```
Mobile Phones
Laptops
Fashion
Books
..
..
```

I am trying to search for the category which i click using datatables.
if i click on laptops the datatable search function to search for 'laptops' in the table.
 javascripts:

```
var table=$('#tableid').DataTable();
$(document).on('click','#search',function(e)
{
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = $('#search').text();
        table.search(search).draw();
});
```

But, whichever category i click on, only the first category is searched. e.g. if i click on 'Fashion', 'Mobile Phones' is being searched. And if i change div id to class all the categories at once are in the search box trying to search.e.g. if i click on any category 'Mobile PhonesLaptopsFashionBooks..' is searched in the table.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. It's not clear what your desired behaviour is

Comment: @Praveen i'm trying to search for the text inside div id search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fnFilter` for filtering the datatables. One thing you need to do is you have to set datatables `searching` property to `true`. I have created a sample to filter the datatable when you click on corresponding div. For reference check this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrrtsteg/7/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="dataTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>                
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
.search {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #73AD21;
    margin-bottom : 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var table = null;

  function createDatatable() {
    table = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        bFilter: false,
        bLengthChange: false,
        searching : true,
        "sDom": 'lfrtip',
        pagingType: 'full',
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "<b><<</b>",
                "sLast": "<b>>></b>",
                "sNext": "<b>></b>",
                "sPrevious": "<b><</b>"
            }
        }
    });
  }

  createDatatable();

 //creating a temp json. you will get this from server side after ajax call 
 var jsonString = '[{"Id": 1,"Name": "Sony Vaio","Category": "Laptops"},{"Id": 2,"Name": "Samsung Galaxy","Category": "Mobile Phones"},{"Id": 3,"Name": "Dell","Category": "Laptops"}]';

        var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        for(i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
                $('#dataTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
                data[i].Id,
            data[i].Name,
            data[i].Category
        ]);
        }

 $(document).on('click','.search',function(e)
{
        var search = $(this).text();
        table.fnFilter(search.trim());
});  

});
```

Comment: this is what i required. But what is wrong with mine.

Comment: I dont know what is happening in your side. for that need your html and js code to reproduce the issue. one thing i noticed is that  **var search = $('#search').text();** is wrong in that case because this will not return the correct clicked element. For getting the correct text we need to use **$(this).text()**